# What is the computational complexity of mean imputation?

Tags: data-imputation

I'm trying to figure out what the complexity of mean imputation is (in $\mathcal{O}$ notation).

Assuming a data set with $m$ observations and $n$ features, I would say the complexity is $\mathcal{O}(m)$ for each feature with missing values. Could anyone confirm or correct this statement?